# Creating columns with lists read from a file in Python

Tags: python, list

I'm currently doing a problem from Starting Out with Programming Logic & Design, Third Edition:

> The Springfork Amateur Golf Club has a tournament every weekend. The club
>   president has asked you to design two programs.
>   (1) A program that will read each player’s name and golf score as keyboard 
>   input, and then save these as records in a file named golf.dat. (Each record
>   will have a field for the player’s name and a field for the player’s score.)
>   (2) A program that reads the records from the golf.dat file and displays them.

I already created the first one no problem. The second one I'm having trouble with. This is my code:

```
    # main module/function
def main():

        # opens the "golf.txt" file created in the Golf Player Input python
        # in read-only mode
    inGolf = open('golf.txt', 'r')
        # reads the player array from the file
    player = inGolf.read()
        # reads the score array from the file
    score = inGolf.read()
        # prints the names and scores

    print player + "   " + score

        # closes the file    
    inGolf.close()

    # calls main function
main()
```

I'm having trouble with displaying the player names and scores. The way I have it displays like this:

```
bob1bill2joe3will4mike5
```

My code for the list in my first program is this:

```
        # loop to get names and scores, both of which are saved in array
counter = 0
while counter < numPlayers:
        # gets the players' names
    player[counter] = raw_input("Please enter the player's name.")
        # writes the names to the file
    outGolf.write(player[counter] )
        # gets the players' scores
    score[counter] = input("Please enter that player's score.")
        # writes the scores to the file
    outGolf.write(str(score[counter]) )
    counter = counter + 1
```

Basically, my question is how do I display the players' names and scores in two nice columns. Am I doing something wrong with the input code or the output code?

I looked through a bunch of answers dealing with formatting columns and everything is more complex than my purposes. This is for an introduction to computer programming class, so a simple fix is what I need!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
def main():
    inGolf = open('golf.txt', 'r')
    names = [] # to store names
    scores = [] # to store scores
    for line in inGolf: # reads file line by line
        line_list = line.split(",") # list formed by each word (separated by comma) 
        names.append(line_list[0]) # append to respective list
        scores.append(line_list[1])

    for i in range(len(names)): # printing
        print "{0:20}{1:10}".format(names[i], scores[i]) # 20 and 10 are the field length

    inGolf.close()

def w(numPlayers): # to write the file
    counter = 0
    outGolf = open('golf.txt', 'w')
    while counter < numPlayers:
        name = raw_input("Please enter the player's name:")
        outGolf.write(name + ",") # separate name and score by a comma
        score = input("Please enter that player's score:")
        outGolf.write(str(score) + "\n") # just add a "\n" to write in different line next time
        counter = counter + 1
    outGolf.close()

w(2)
main()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but that is way too complicated for me!

Comment: Tell me what don't you understand, all what I used is simple so with a little explanation you will get it!

Comment: Oh, I see. Did you combine the two chunks of code I added? That's where I got confused. They are supposed to be two separate codes. Also, what is the 2 in the parenthesis of w() for?

Comment: The numberOfPlayers you want to write in the file. And I don't think I've combined the two chunks of your code, why are you telling that?

Comment: Because there were two separate programs I quoted: one that gets the names and scores and one that prints the names and scores. But the way you have it makes it easy to split up. Thank you, however, this helps a lot.

Comment: Reading your statements, I think I did it correctly: (1) Take an input and write it to file. (2) Read from file and print them.

Answer (score 0):

Please add

```
print player + "   " + score + "\n"
```

This will solve your first problem.

If you want to do more formatting in string then String has formatting functionality

[String Formatting Operations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

You are storing data in simple format. If you use CSV then it will be easy to read.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but all that did was add an extra line to the "bob1bill2joe3will4mike5".. Do you think it has something to do with how the information is being saved in the second chunk of code? Like, maybe it's being saved as bob1bill2... without any spaces or breaks. How can I fix that?

Comment: The only thing my professor taught us is to use outGolf.write(str(score[counter] + "\n") but then it prints with the names and scores all on separate lines.

Comment: Your professor might be right :). Generally when we store data then use database. If we dont have to use database then use CSV. Its easy to read by other other utility like Excel etc. In future if you want to convert that to database then all database has support to import data from CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code that writes to the file should be

```
# loop to get names and scores, both of which are saved in array
counter = 0
while counter < numPlayers:
    # gets the players' names
    player = raw_input("Please enter the player's name.")
    # gets the players' scores
    score = input("Please enter that player's score.")

    # Write the scores to the file in a comma-separated format
    outGolf.write(player+','+score+'\n')
    counter = counter + 1
```

Then, when you want to make a pretty display

```
# main module/function
def main():
    # opens the "golf.txt" file created in the Golf Player Input python
    # in read-only mode
    inGolf = open('golf.txt', 'r')
    # reads the player array from the file
    allRecords = inGolf.readlines()
    # print the data
    for record in allRecords:
        player = record.split(',')[0]
        score = record.split(',')[1]

        print player + "\t" + score + "\n"

    # closes the file    
inGolf.close()

# calls main function
main()
```

Comment: In the first chunk of code, you forgot the str(score) :P It gave me an error how you did it. But thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for. The second chunk of code gave me this error: line 10, in main
    score = record.split(',')[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: In the first chunk of code, you don't need the `str()` because by default all input you read from the command line is interpreted as a string

Comment: The second part, well that means one of the lines in your code does not have a comma. Go through it manually to see if there are any blank lines in there. Alternately, you can explore the `try-catch` framework of python.

Answer (score 0):

The file.read() method with no arguments reads the file till the EOF(end of file), so in your examle the `score` will be empty string and `player == bob1bill2joe3will4mike5`. And it's better to add end of line character('\n') so that you could iterate over content of your file.

Answer (score 0):

For this question - the correct answer to read the file is a bit simpler than I initially thought:

```
file=open('golf.txt','r')
name=True
for line in file:
 if name:
        print('Name:'+line,end='')
 else:
        print('Score:'+line)
 name = not name

 file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('golf.txt', 'r') as file:
    name = True
    for line in file:
        if name:
            print(f'Name:{line}', end='')
        else:
            print(f'Score:{line}')
        name = not name
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**